# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class Button at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag

Tags: android, xml

This is my xml file code :-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/White">
       <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Login with FACEBOOK"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/facebooklogo"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is java file :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
       }
}
```

LOGCAT :-

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> >     ComponentInfo{aavid.rks.blablacar/aavid.rks.blablacar.LoginActivity}:
> >     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error
> >     inflating class Button
> >
> > Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7:
> >     Error inflating class Button at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
> >
> > Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
> >     is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020047 a=-1
> >     r=0x7f020047}at
> >     android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2063)

Comment: have you missed the button's closing tag in copy/paste or in your code too??

Comment: check facebooklogo in your drawable folder

Comment: I forget  .. still issue is there. its not issue my mistake..

Comment: problem is with your facebook logo image. I think the type you are using is not supported

Comment: facebooklogo.png(v21) is there in drawable folder

Comment: try edit name to `facebooklogo.png`

Comment: oh yah its works...convert name into **facebooklogo.png** instead of **facebooklogo.png(v21)**.. works

Comment: if you have check you logcat...you might have got this error `res\drawable\xxxxxx.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]` at your `facebooklogo` while copmling..

Answer (score 1):

Do check your facebooklogo size.
Also make sure you keep all the resources names lower cased, That causes the issue of xml parser. 
In your case

> @color/White

Comment: resource identifiers, everything must be lower case, so an uppercase Color wouldn't work, even if the resource you were trying to access existed in the appropriate namespace.

Answer (score 0):

change your code....you have incomplete xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/White">
       <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Login with FACEBOOK"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/facebooklogo" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```